# java io stream not working correctly on Jboss EAP 6 or Jboss 7.1.2 on Linux

Tags: java, jboss7.x, iostream

I am trying to read contents of a pdf (which is at http://alf.dev.internalserver.com/alfresco/s/api/node/workspace/SpacesStore/8420d34c-7bac-488f-8fe7-e4070b2d2812/content )  by opening a connection using http client and then read the inpustream and write to ouputstream. (Yes this url is accessible only to our intarnet :) )

The code works on

1. On my windowsxp box as a standalone java client.
2. On Jboss 7.1.2 running on windowsxp as part of war file.
3. On our linux box as a standalone java client.

But this code fails to read the PDF correctly

1. On Jboss 7.1.2 running on linux as part of war file.

In successful case when I read the pdf from the given url and print the size, I see that we get around **36289  bytes**.

In case 2 when running on  jboss on linux for any pdf document irrespective of the size, I get only **970 bytes** read rest is not read.The beauty is there are no exceptions any where. Obviously the saved pdf cant be opened since the pdf content is not read completely.

Here is the code that reads the data from  inputStream (which is of type )

```
    protected void streamPdfOut(InputStream in, HttpServletResponse resp)
                throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {

            ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();
            resp.reset();
            resp.setContentType("application/pdf");
            resp.setHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=List.pdf");
            resp.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server
            LOGGER.debug("InputStream type = "+ in);
            //LOGGER.debug(" Loaded from :"+ in.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource());
            byte buff[] = IOUtils.toByteArray(in);
            LOGGER.debug(" IOUtils Number of bytes read count ="+ buff.length);
            out.write(buff, 0, buff.length);
            LOGGER.info("bytesReadTotal [" + buff.length + "]");
            // clean up
            out.flush();
            resp.flushBuffer();
            out.close();
            //close input stream and release any system resources.
            in.close();
        }
```

**NOTE:**
The inputstream is opened using Apache HTTPclient (I haven't copied the code here)

**LOG output (On windows xp running on JBOSS 7.1.2):**
DEBUG PDFServletHelperImpl:80 InputStream type = org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@34529788
DEBUG PDFServletHelperImpl:83  IOUtils Number of bytes read count =36289
INFO  PDFServletHelperImpl:85 bytesReadTotal [36289]

**LOG output (On Linux running on JBOSS 7.1.2):**
DEBUG PDFServletHelperImpl:80 InputStream type = org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@ab16d7
DEBUG PDFServletHelperImpl:83  IOUtils Number of bytes read count =970
INFO  PDFServletHelperImpl:85 bytesReadTotal [970]

To makesure that the classes that are being loaded are not different on jboss on my local and on the linux box on jboss, I printed the path where the class is getting loaded and on both linux and windows version of our webapp I see that the class "org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream" is loaded from httpclient-4.1.jar  which is in war file.

Any suggestion on what is restricting the app from reading just 970 bytes and not the entire pdf stream just when i run the code on Linux version for jboss 7.1.2?

Comment: It may be downloading something else.. What's the content of the 970 bytes, say if you parse it as string maybe using IOUtils.toString or something?

Comment: its the first few bytes of the PDF. I even hardcoded the exact same url and it stoped reading beyond 970 bytes. I tried another document had the same issue.